# Firebase-admin Firestore node.js share logic with modular v9 js sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

What is the recommended way to share Firestore api logic (between the admin node.js and the js web) when upgrading to the web v9 modular sdk?
The way I did it before was just supplying the db (and deleteField) if it was used by a serverless function.

```js
// admin db init
import { FieldValue, getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore"
const FSAdmin = createFirebaseAdminApp(options);
const db = getFirestore(FSAdmin)
```

That no longer seems to work as if you try to use the `getFirestore(FSAdmin)` with the v9 docRef `doc(db, collectionName, documentID)` it will give you an error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the function getFirestore(FSAdmin) and getFirestore(FSAdmin) does not get what it expects.  As I can't see your complete configuration and debug information, it's a bit difficult to tell the full context of the error. As it is stated in the Firebase docs [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), make sure to call initializeApp(firebaseConfig); including the proper configuration before you use Firestore in your app.
Also check that you have the latest version of all your Firebase packages installed. I also know that Firebase has recently got quite some library changes, as Firebase also strives to minify itself.

Note that there are two packages:

const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');

and

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

In addition, I could not find createFirebaseAdminApp() and getFirestore() in the current function list of the Firebase docs, so I think they changed the signature completely.

[Firebase/JS all signatures.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin)

I hope I could help you at least a bit.

Comment: The `getFirestore(FSAdmin)` works fine by itself, the problem here is that the admin sdk still uses the old namespace `(db.collection("collID").doc("docID")` format instead of the newer modular format (`doc(db, "collID", "docID"`).
createFirebaseAdminApp is just a function I made that initialises or returns firebase admin.

Comment: It seems like the Firebase documentation could be a lot more extensive and maybe even provide some examples of usage. Probably you won't be the last person with such questions.